# Ensure user input = String, not int type

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a new Scanner object to obtain 
    System.out.println("Please enter the word you are looking for");
    // input from System.in
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userin  = input.next();
```

My goal is to write a loop that analyzes the input of the user to ensure that it is a `String` which doesn't represent an `int`. If int then I wish to return an error message

Comment: _All_ inputs are going to be strings. They might be strings with numbers in them, but that's still a string.

Comment: `input.next` returns a sequence of characters.  Thus it is always a `String` by definition.  If they type in 12345, then the result will be a `String` with the five characters `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'`.  If you want to disallow inputs unless they contain at least one letter (or something like that), that can be done.  But I think that first you need to get over your confusion about types.

Comment: We need clarification here.. input.next() gets String. But how do you define "int"? Do you define it as "numbers only", or "int" data type in java?

Comment: andymancan, did my answer help you? Please ask for clarification if needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Each input will be a `String` as `String`s might represent also numerical sequences of characters.
2. You can validate the input using regex.

The following code should help:

```
String userin  = input.next();
if (userin.matches("[0-9a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*")) {
    //input contains only small and large letters. At least one character.
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("The input must be single word and mustn't contain digits only");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As others have said, every input will be a String. If you want to reject Strings that are composed only of number characters, e.g. "1234", you could check if it's an integer a few different ways - maybe loop through the String and call isDigit() on each character, or pass the String into parseInt and catch a NumberFormatException.